# Code for generating tiles/grids on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles, grids-graticules

I would like to create a featurecollection of tiles/grids (like attached image) that covers an entire state. Is there anyway to create such a grid where each side of the rectangle is 100-meter for example?

So, the code for creating tiles/grids is what I am looking for.
That is where I am stuck.

P.S. I found this code that creates points, but not rectangles: https://mygeoblog.com/2019/01/25/regular-grid/

[image]

Comment: Please do not delete and re-ask the same question.

Comment: I am sorry, my original question was blocked/closed! so, I had to re-ask. now this one is closed as duplicate!!! it seems I have to re-ask again

Comment: Please do not re-ask. Instead edit your original question to improve it so that it can be reviewed by the community to decide whether it is suitable for re-opening.

Comment: Surely, if you have code that generates square features, you could start to modify it to generate rectangular ones.